# replacing deprecated AudioSessionSetProperty

Tags: ios, ios7

```
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration, sizeof(bufferLength), &bufferLength);
```

How can I per lace this method in iOS 7??

Comment: `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AudioSession api was deprecated in iOS7 in favor of [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class. To replace your call you need to use `setPreferredIOBufferDuration:error:` method:

```
NSError* error;
[session setPreferredIOBufferDuration:bufferLength error:&error];
```

Note also that buffer `duration` is not the same as buffer size, buffer size should be enough to hold duration time of audio data.